# Can not get sugar to notice my entrypoint of module

Tags: php, smarty, crm, sugarcrm

I am trying to install a module manually. Trying to learn and understand the system. It somewhat works because I created this directory

```
/modules/Wowproducts/views/view.list.php
```

```
class WowproductsViewList extends ViewList
{
    public function display()
    {
        echo 'test';
        $GLOBALS['mod_strings'] = return_module_language($GLOBALS['current_language'], 'Calendar');
        //require_once('modules/Calendar/index.php');
    }
}
```

I am able to see the word test when i type in

```
index.php?module=Wowproducts&action=index
```

and I see it

It however is not detecting my entry point file

Wowproducts.php

Answer (score 0):

Wowproducts.php is your bean file, not entrypoint file. This class is called only if you instantiate the Wowproducts class somewhere in your code.